# How to write lambda function using GraphQL and Mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aws-lambda, graphql, graphql-js

I am new GraphQL and I read article about GraphQL, it is similar to my expected out, but I didn't understand, how to use it in aws lambda function. I have two collections 1) user_posts 2)user_profile. Find the below collection data for your reference.

1) user_posts collection

```
_id :ObjectId("5d519f861c9d4400005ebd1b")
userid : ObjectId("5d518caed55bc00001d235c1")
media : "hello.jpg"
type : "jpg"
created : " "
modified : " "
like : Array
       0 : Object
           userid : ObjectId("5d518caed55bc00001d235c1")
           status : "like"
       1 : Object
           userid : ObjectId("5d518da6d55bc00001d235c2")
           status : "happy"
comment : Array
       0 : Object
           userid : ObjectId("5d518caed55bc00001d235c1")
           comment : "hello"
       1 : Object
           userid : ObjectId("5d518da6d55bc00001d235c2")
           comment : "welcome"
share : Array
       0 : Object
           userid : ObjectId("5d518caed55bc00001d235c1")
           status : "shared"
       1 : Object
           userid : ObjectId("5d518da6d55bc00001d235c2")
           status : "shared"
```

2) User_profile collection

```
 _id : ObjectId("5d518caed55bc00001d235c1")
 username : "ramesh",
 photo :  " ",
 created : " ",
 modified : " "

 _id : ObjectId("5d518da6d55bc00001d235c2")
 username : "shekar",
 photo :  " ",
 created : " ",
 modified : " "
```

generally i am using lambda function to get the output like this. but it is not getting my expected output.

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID;
var databasename = "trans_db";
var db;

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {

 var Userid = event['userid'];
 var uid = ObjectId(Userid);

 MongoClient.connect(uri,{ useNewUrlParser: true }, (error, client) => {
 if (error) return 1;    // Checking the connection
 console.log('Connection Successful');
 db = client.db(databasename);

 db.collection("user_posts").find({"userid" : uid}).toArray(function(err, 
 res) {
    if (err) throw err;

    context.succeed(res);
    });
  });
  };
```

I need output like this below.

```
_id :ObjectId("5d519f861c9d4400005ebd1b")
userid : ObjectId("5d518caed55bc00001d235c1")
username : "ramesh"
photo : " ",
media : "hello.jpg"
type : "jpg"
created : " "
modified : " "
like : Array
       0 : Object
           userid : ObjectId("5d518caed55bc00001d235c1")
           status : "like"
           username : "ramesh"
           photo : " "
       1 : Object
           username : "shekar"
           photo : " "
           userid : ObjectId("5d518da6d55bc00001d235c2")
           status : "happy"
           username : "shekar"
           photo : " "
comment : Array
       0 : Object
           userid : ObjectId("5d518caed55bc00001d235c1")
           comment : "hello"
           username : "ramesh"
           photo : " "
       1 : Object
           userid : ObjectId("5d518da6d55bc00001d235c2")
           comment : "welocme"
           username : "shekar"
           photo : " "
share : Array
       0 : Object
           userid : ObjectId("5d518caed55bc00001d235c1")
           status : "shared"
           username : "ramesh"
           photo : " "
       1 : Object
           userid : ObjectId("5d518da6d55bc00001d235c2")
           status : "shared"
           username : "shekar"
           photo : " "
```

Comment: what is your MongoDB version? And Why aren't using mongoose?

Comment: @Ashok I am using mongodb atlas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need mongo min version 3.6.

Update your schema base on `user_posts` return for get query which is below.

Mongodb Query

```
 MongoClient.connect(uri,{ useNewUrlParser: true }, (error, client) => {
    if (error) return 1;    // Checking the connection
    console.log('Connection Successful');
    db = client.db(databasename);
    db.collection("user_posts").aggregate(
    { $match: {"userid" : uid}},
    { $unwind: '$like' },
    { $lookup: { from: "users", localField: "like.userid", foreignField: "_id", as: "users" }},
    { $group: {
        _id: "$_id",
        like: { $push: { $mergeObjects: ['$like', { $arrayElemAt: [ "$users", 0 ] } ]}},
        data: { $first: "$$ROOT" }
    }},
    { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: { $mergeObjects: ['$data', { like: "$like"} ]} } }
    { $unwind: '$comment' },
    { $lookup: { from: "users", localField: "comment.userid", foreignField: "_id", as: "users" }},
    { $group: {
        _id: "$_id",
            comment: { $push: { $mergeObjects: ['$comment', { $arrayElemAt: [ "$users", 0 ] } ]}},
            data: { $first: "$$ROOT" }
    }},
    { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: { $mergeObjects: ['$data', { comment: "$comment"} ]} } }
    { $unwind: '$share' },
    { $lookup: { from: "users", localField: "share.userid", foreignField: "_id", as: "users" }},
    { $group: {
        _id: "$_id",
        share: { $push: { $mergeObjects: ['$share', { $arrayElemAt: [ "$users", 0 ] } ]}},
        data: { $first: "$$ROOT" }
    }},
    { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: { $mergeObjects: ['$data', { share: "$share"} ]} } },
    { $project: { users: 0 }}
    ).then(res => {
       context.succeed(res);
    }).catch(error => {
       console.log({ error })
    });
```

GraphQL

```
 user_posts {
     _id
    userid
    username
    photo 
    media
    type 
    created
    modified 
    like {
        userid
        username
        status
        photo 
    }
    comment {
        userid
        username
        status
        photo 
    }
    share {
        userid
        username
        status
        photo 
    }
 }
```

Change in resolver in graphql based on query in graphql we can simplified mongodb query but for now we have to focuse on Graphql

Comment: If you don't mine can you please help with the solution for the below question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57629210/how-to-store-mongodb-output-in-variable-using-nodejs-in-lambda-function?noredirect=1#comment101712154_57629210