# Is it possible to use group aggregation in invoke lamda function?

Tags: python, aws-lambda

I have created three lambda functions 1).postData 2).like 3).comment. I am using invoke lambda function to combine three output. Find the below code for your reference.

```
lambdas = boto3.client("lambda")

def lambda_handler(event, context):

print("Received event: " + json.dumps(event, indent=1))

response1 = lambdas.invoke(FunctionName="postdata", 
InvocationType="RequestResponse", Payload=json.dumps(event, 
default=json_util.default));

response2 = lambdas.invoke(FunctionName="like", 
InvocationType="RequestResponse", Payload=json.dumps(event, 
default=json_util.default));

response3 = lambdas.invoke(FunctionName="comment", 
InvocationType="RequestResponse", Payload=json.dumps(event, 
default=json_util.default));

result1 = json.loads(response1.get('Payload').read())
result2 = json.loads(response2.get('Payload').read())
result3 = json.loads(response3.get('Payload').read())

return result1+result2+result3
```

here i getting three lambda functions out in one array. In three lambda functions, we have one unique id but three different filed names.like the below

```
[
```

### {

```
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "5d6fbc4256cfe9fcfd8c4136"
  },
  "location": null,
  "media_type": "jpg",
},
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "5d5dd01d93ab7d1ed7e2ff31"
  },
  "location": null,
  "media_type": "jpg",
```

### },

### {

```
 "from": {
    "$oid": "5d5dcccf9cf5ce000183d15e"
  },
  "to": {
    "$oid": "5d5dd01d93ab7d1ed7e2ff31"
  },
  "interaction_type": "feelings",
},
{
 "from": {
    "$oid": "5d5dcccf9cf5ce000183d15e"
  },
  "to": {
    "$oid": "5d6fbc4256cfe9fcfd8c4136"
  },
  "interaction_type": "feelings",
```

### },

### {

```
  "from": {
    "$oid": "5d5dcccf9cf5ce000183d15e"
  },
  "to": {
    "$oid": "5d5dd01d93ab7d1ed7e2ff31"
  },
  "interaction_data": "nice car.....",
},
{
  "from": {
    "$oid": "5d5dcccf9cf5ce000183d15e"
  },
  "to": {
    "$oid": "5d5dd01d93ab7d1ed7e2ff31"
  },
  "interaction_data": "awesome car.....",
},
{
  "from": {
    "$oid": "5d5dcccf9cf5ce000183d15e"
  },
  "to": {
    "$oid": "5d6fbc4256cfe9fcfd8c4136"
  },
  "interaction_data": "Hello world....",
```

### }

```
]
```

I have divided the output with bold braces getpost, like, comment outputs.
My concern is getpost -"_id", like - "to", comment - "to" fields values are unique. based on this unique value, can i group the output. means I need _id, to fileds values same,that values will display in one array. is it possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options here.

1. Create one lambda that will run all three queries, and aggregate there (example of mongo grouping below).
2. Parse your JSON response objects, if they have not been parsed already, and manually aggregate.

Obviously #1 will be more performant, and is way more elegant.

Mongo aggregate/group function example:

```
db.sales.aggregate(
   [
      {
        $group : {
           _id : { month: { $month: "$date" }, day: { $dayOfMonth: "$date" }, year: { $year: "$date" } },
           totalPrice: { $sum: { $multiply: [ "$price", "$quantity" ] } },
           averageQuantity: { $avg: "$quantity" },
           count: { $sum: 1 }
        }
      }
   ]
)
```

If you decide to go the mongo grouping route  in your lambda, please keep in mind that it uses in memory storage while it is calculating. If your data set is huge this will give you an error. If you run into that issue set `allowDiskUse` to true as the docs suggest.

See:

- https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/

Comment: my concern is, how to apply group aggregation in the above code. is it possible because this is invoke lambda function. I didn't understand the above solution.

Comment: Hi, if you have a time, can you please answer the below query   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57996739/how-to-write-matched-condition-for-array-values     Thanks in advance