# How to write match condition for array values?

Tags: python, mongodb, aggregation-framework, pymongo

I have stored values in multiple variables. below are the input variables.

```
uid = Objectid("5d518caed55bc00001d235c1")
disuid = ['5d76b2c847c8d3000184a090', '5d7abb7a97a90b0001326010']
```

These values are changed dynamically. and below is my code:

```
user_posts.aggregate([{
    "$match": {
        "$or": [{ "userid": uid }, {
            "userid": {
                "$eq":
                    disuid
            }
        }]
    }
},
{
    "$lookup": {
        "from": "user_profile",
        "localField": "userid",
        "foreignField": "_id",
        "as": "details"
    }
},
{ "$unwind": "$details" },
{
    "$sort": { "created_ts": -1 }
},
{
    "$project": {
        "userid": 1,
        "type": 1,
        "location": 1,
        "caption": 1
    }
}
])
```

In the above code, I am getting matched **uid** values only but I need documents matched to **disuid** also.

In **userid** field, we have stored "Objectid" values only. 
So my concern is how to add "Objectid" to "disuid" variable and how to write match condition for both variables using userid field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok you can do it in two ways :

As you've this :

```
uid = Objectid("5d518caed55bc00001d235c1")
disuid = ['5d76b2c847c8d3000184a090', '5d7abb7a97a90b0001326010']
```

You need to convert your list of strings to list of ObjectId's using python code :

```
from bson.objectid import ObjectId


disuid = ['5d76b2c847c8d3000184a090', '5d7abb7a97a90b0001326010']
my_list = []


for i in disuid:
    my_list.append(ObjectId(i))
```

It will look like this : 
`[ObjectId('5d76b2c847c8d3000184a090'),ObjectId('5d7abb7a97a90b0001326010')]`

then by using new list `my_list`, you can do query like this :

```
user_posts.aggregate([{"$match" : { "$or" : [{ "userid" : uid }, { "userid" : { "$in" : my_list }}]}}])
```

Or in the other way which I wouldn't prefer, as converting just few in code is easier compared to n num of values for `userid` field over all documents in DB, but just in case if you want it to be done using DB query :

```
user_posts.aggregate([{$addFields : {userStrings : {$toString: '$userid'}}},{"$match" : { "$or" : [{ "userid" : uid }, { "userStrings" : { "$in" : disuid }}]}}])
```

**Note :** In case if you don't have bson package, then you need to install it by doing something like `pip install bson`

Comment: Bro can you please help with the solution. please find the below link   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58573157/how-to-search-letter-in-list-array-using-python/58573214?noredirect=1#comment103471520_58573214

Comment: @RameshReddy : Sorry I'm a bit completely busy with my stuff, Please check my answer !!