# How to find strings with matched letters in list/array using lambda function?

Tags: python, mongodb, lambda

I am using lambda function, python 3.6 and Mongodb atlas. In mongodb i have one collection below like this. collection name profile. below as the collection structure.

```
"_id" : ObjectId("5db234df92b0ce00016932f3")
"username" : "testing"
"channel" : [ "abc", "efg", "cde", "xyz" ]
"about" : "this is a test case"
```

we have multiple rows similar to the above. Now i am using python, i write the lambda function to find strings matched letter in channel array.find the below lambda function.

```
profile = db.profile
name = event['cname']

ch = list(profile.aggregate([{
    "$match" : { "username" : "testing" }
    }, 
    {
        "$project" : {
            "channel" : 1
            }
    }
    ]))

ch1 = json.loads(json.dumps(ch, default=json_util.default))
ch2 = [document["channel"] for document in ch1]
new_list = []
for i in ch2:
    if(re.findall(name, i)):
        new_list.append(i)  
return new_list
```

I have passed "cname" : "c" in event. but i am getting error like this.

```
Response:
{
 "errorMessage": "expected string or bytes-like object",
 "errorType": "TypeError",
 "stackTrace": [
[
  "/var/task/lambda_function.py",
  51,
  "lambda_handler",
  "if(re.findall(search, i)):"
],
[
  "/var/lang/lib/python3.6/re.py",
  222,
  "findall",
  "return _compile(pattern, flags).findall(string)"
]
]
}
```

I tried with re.search also but i am getting same, I need output like this below.

```
Input: "cname" : "c"
output: "abc"
        "cde"
```

can you please help me with solution, thanks on advance.

Comment: Can you print and check what you're getting in name & ch, check the type of those two, as in your other question name should be a string & ch should be an array/list of strings !! Something like this :: type(name), if they're not string then you've to convert those like str(name)

Comment: @srinivasy I have checked in "name" what i have passed in "event", it is display in "name"  and in "ch", array list is display

Comment: I mean to say you need to check all values inside ch2 should be strings & also name should be a string, is that what you're seeing ?

Comment: @srinivasy bro I have checked values, all are in strings. when i print ch2: [['abc', 'efg', 'cde', 'xyz' ]]. I removed one bracket using ch3 = (', '.join(map(str, ch2))). now i am getting array only single brackets. now it's working but i getting the output like this, when i pass "c" as a input, output like [ "c", "c" ] not display the matched entire strings

Comment: Can you put the entire code here, is should not happen like that when name is a string which is checked against list of strings..

Comment: @srinivasy                                                                                                       
 ch2 = [document["channel"] for document in ch]
 ch3 = (', '.join(map(str, ch2)))
    
    new_list = []
    for i in ch3:
        if(re.findall(name, i)):
            new_list.append(i)
    
    return new_list

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201739/discussion-between-ramesh-reddy-and-srinivasy).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the below code:

```
 ch2 = [document["channel"] for document in ch]
 new_list = []

 for word in ch2[0]:
    print(word)
    if(re.findall(name, word)):
        new_list.append(word)

  return new_list
```

the issue has been resolved