# How to search matched list in Json output using python in lambda function?

Tags: python, mongodb

I have two collections community and profile.

community collection sample data:

```
_id : ObjectId("5dc1f30abcafe70001bd0075")
communityname : "testing1",
user_id : ObjectId("5dc1f2ed4a59120001a4d09d")
active_flag : 0

_id : ObjectId("5dc1f30abcafe70001bd0082")
communityname : "testing1",
user_id : ObjectId("5dc4a8b7360a0100012d3ec8")
active_flag : 0
```

profile collection sample data:

```
_id : ObjectId("5dc1f2ed4a59120001a4d09d"),
username : "Haneesh",
"name" : "hani"

_id : ObjectId("5dc4a8b7360a0100012d3ec8"),
username : "Harish",
name : "Hari"
```

I write the lambda function like this below.

```
 community =db.community

    comm_id = ObjectId(event['c_id'])

    user1 = list(community.aggregate([{
        "$match" : { "_id" : comm_id }
        }, 
        {
            "$lookup" : {
                "from" : "profile",
                "localField" : "user_id",
                "foreignField" : "_id",
                "as" : "details"
            }
        },
        { "$unwind" : "$details" },
        {
            "$project" : {
                "_id" : 0,
                "username" : "$details.username",
                "name" : "$details.name"
                }
        }
        ]))

    user2 = json.loads(json.dumps(user1, default=json_util.default))
    return user2
```

I have executed the lambda function, I'm getting output like this below:

```
[
  {
    "username": "anvithpm026",
    "name": "Anvith P M"
  },
  {
    "username": "shailu",
    "name": "shail"
  },
  {
    "username": "sukumar",
    "name": "suku"
  }
]
```

Now my concern is, how to search matched list. Example if a letter matchs with the username, then it get the username along with name. I've tried to use the regular expression but it didn't work. Please help me with a solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @srinivasy I have edited my question.

Comment: Hey quick question, seems like I miss understood your question, After looking into your collections I understood you've to keep that query as is, So do you want to make this work on python code ? On output  array of aggregation ? Where do you or how do you pass username ?

Comment: Also your question is so confusing if you're doing $match to filter documents ("$match" : { "_id" : comm_id }) in first step on unique ID(_id), then all you'll get is an object in response !! how are you getting an array in output ??

Comment: @srinivasy  every community has mutliple userid and we have multiple communities. so I write the match condition first and getting only one particular community user_id then lookup with profile collection to get the username and name

Comment: So you mean to say user_id can be an array?

Comment: @srinivasy yes bro

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202285/discussion-between-srinivasy-and-ramesh-reddy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A minor tweak does the job, below is the query :

```
user1 = list(community.aggregate([{
    "$match": { "_id": ObjectId("5dc1f30abcafe70001bd0075") }
},
{
    "$lookup": {
        "from": "profile",
        "localField": "user_id",
        "foreignField": "_id",
        "as": "details"
    }
}, { "$unwind": "$details" }, { "$match": { "details.username": /eesh/i } }, {
    "$project": {
        "_id": 0,
        "username": "$details.username",
        "name": "$details.name"
    }
}]))
```

Please pass `/eesh/i` dynamically as per your requirement. In the other way I've tried to add this filter `{ "details.username": /eesh/i }` in `$lookup` itself - that way we can avoid following `$unwind` & `$match` stages, But as we've two filters to be checked - due to few limitations on using `regex` in `$expr` of `$match`, this query is the one & even this is easier to do.

Comment: Bro, if you don't mine can you please give the solution of the below query   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58937282/how-to-implement-mongodb-connection-pooling-in-lambda-function-using-pymongo